# css centering the rotating cube

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a rotating text in a hexagonal shape like on this site https://www.observian.com/, but right now it is not centered on the screen. It keeps moving to the top of the page. What should I do to make this cube always centered in x and y axis?

```css
    .stage {
                margin: 1em auto;
                -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
                -moz-perspective: 1200px;
                -ms-perspective: 1200px;
                perspective: 1200px;
                /*transform:perspective(400px) translate(0px, -85px) rotateX(90deg);*/
                 
            }

            .spinner5 div {
                position: absolute;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
            }

            @keyframes spinner5 {
                from, 15% {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(0);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(0);
                    transform: rotateX(0) ;
                    border:thin solid red;
                }
                20%, 35% {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg);
                    transform: rotateX(72deg) ;
                    border:thin solid green;
                }
                40%, 55% {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg);
                    transform: rotateX(144deg) ;
                    border:thin solid blue;
                    
                }
                60%, 75% {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg);
                    transform: rotateX(216deg) ;
                    border:thin solid black;
                }
                80%, 95% {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(288deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(288deg);
                    transform: rotateX(288deg) ;
                    border:thin solid yellow;
                }
                to {
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    transform: rotateX(360deg) ;
                    border:thin solid orange;
                }
            }

            .spinner5 {
                -webkit-animation-name: spinner5;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
                animation-name: spinner5;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                animation-duration: 20s;
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                
                 
            }
            .spinner5  div{
                font-size:95px;
                color:green;
                width:500px;
                background-color:yellow;
                text-align:center;
                height:110px;
                transform:scale(-1, -1);
            }
```

```html
<div class="stage" style="width: 240px; height: 160px;margin-top:200px">
            <div class="spinner5">
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); " >text1 </div>
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 2</div>
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 3</div>
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 4</div>
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 5 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i put the code on https://jsfiddle.net/araneta/486htkqn/2/

Answer (score 0):

First reset all ***padding*** and ***margin*** using a *universal selector*, then you add ***width*** and ***height*** to the parent element `.stage` as ***view width*** and ***view height*** units of measurement =>  `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`, then add a ***calculated measurement*** to and **top padding** => `padding-top: calc(50vh - 55px);` and ***left padding*** => `padding-left: calc(50vw - 250px);`

`55px` is *half* the **height** of your ***spinner elements*** and `250px` is *half* the **width** of the ***spinner elements***. Then your ***parent element*** will simply add `padding left` ***50 view width*** and ***50 view height*** *minus* the ***width*** and ***height*** of the ***spinner*** elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stage {
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -ms-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  /*transform:perspective(400px) translate(0px, -85px) rotateX(90deg);*/
  padding-top: calc(50vh - 55px);
  padding-left: calc(50vw - 250px)
}

.spinner5 div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

@keyframes spinner5 {
  from,
  15% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0);
    transform: rotateX(0);
    border: thin solid red;
  }
  20%,
  35% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    transform: rotateX(72deg);
    border: thin solid green;
  }
  40%,
  55% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    transform: rotateX(144deg);
    border: thin solid blue;
  }
  60%,
  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    transform: rotateX(216deg);
    border: thin solid black;
  }
  80%,
  95% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(288deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(288deg);
    transform: rotateX(288deg);
    border: thin solid yellow;
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    border: thin solid orange;
  }
}

.spinner5 {
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner5;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-name: spinner5;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.spinner5 div {
  font-size: 95px;
  color: green;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  height: 110px;
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <div class="spinner5">
    <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px); ">text1 </div>
    <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 2</div>
    <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 3</div>
    <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 4</div>
    <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); -moz-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); -ms-transform: rotateX(288deg) translateZ(110px); ">text 5 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```